# NetworkX: build random graph with 2 cluster

Tags: python, networkx

I need to build a graph with 2 clusters and random connectivities between them.
I use

```
G = nx.powerlaw_cluster_graph(128, 2364, 0.5)
```

I need 128 nodes, 2364 edges, and 2 clusters.
It returns an error and the wrong graph.
Is there any way to do this?
I need to get something like this:
[image: pic]

Comment: It would help if you attach the error message as well:
"NetworkXError must have m>1 and m<n, m=%d,n=%d"%(m,n))
networkx.exception.NetworkXError: NetworkXError must have m>1 and m<n, m=2364,n=128

Comment: Edited English/grammar

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error message. 
As per [documentation](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.random_graphs.powerlaw_cluster_graph.html) I believe that instead of 2364 you need 2364/128 ~ 18 (the edges per node to be added).

This is not going to get you two linked clusters but rather one graph with connectivity guided by the last parameter.
To have two clusters connected I would create two separate random graphs (in the same way you do currently) and add a few random connections afterwards (randomly picking pairs of vertices - one from each graph). This seems easiest to me.

Comment: I add a picture what I try to get

Comment: I saw the error, that it need average edges to one node, but how create 2 subgraph there? I try to change p, but there is only 1 cluster

Comment: There are lots of ways to get 2 subgraphs.  But whatever way you do that, it's not going to naturally emerge from an algorithm that isn't designed to produce 2 subgraphs.  What method should be used to create two subgraphs depends on why you need to create such a graph.  Why do you need 2 subgraphs?

Comment: @Joel I need to compare random graph with 2 cluster with graph of molecular machine

Comment: Then what you need to do is spend some time working out what you mean by a "random graph with 2 clusters".  What is the null model that you're trying to compare the graph to.  Once you figure out what that null model is, then you'll need to figure out how to generate that graph and then do the comparison.